# Keyboard Shortcut Stuck on Disable

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using the Logitech MK710 keyboard. There are additional function keys on the thing, and some work but some do not. For example, the email fn key does open Mail, but the calculator button does not work. Trying to set it in settings does not work. Any ideas how to get these keys working?

Thanks!

Comment: Did it work on another Linux distro? Not all wireless keyboards work properly on Linux. By the way, for setting a custom keyboard shortcut for Calculator, the command is `pantheon-calculator`.